# Install library on azure function linux from DevOps pipeline

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli

Is there a way to connect to the azure function linux machine from Azure Devops? I just have a service connection, no portal access of any kind. I need to install a library on the worker. I have tried the following

```
    # Set variables
    $serviceName = "my-function-app"
    $resourceGroupName = "my-resource-group"
    $libraryName = "my-library"
    
    # Get service principal credentials from service connection
    $connection = Get-AzServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName "my-service-connection"
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($connection.ApplicationId, (ConvertTo-SecureString $connection.Secret -AsPlainText -Force))
    
    # Connect to Azure using service principal credentials
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $credential -TenantId $connection.TenantId
    
    # Get Azure Function details
    $functionApp = Get-AzFunctionApp -Name $serviceName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
    
    # Install library on Azure Function
    $command = "apt-get install $libraryName"
    Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -VMName $functionApp.Name -CommandId 'RunShellScript' -ScriptType 'Inline' -Script "$command"
```

this just gets stuck and this one

```
 functionAppName="funcrionname"
    resourceGroup="RGName"
    serviceConnectionName="ConNanme"
    
    # Get instance details
    instance=$(az functionapp show --name $functionAppName --resource-group $resourceGroup --query "defaultHostName" -otsv | awk -F '.' '{print $1}')
    
    # Get access token from service connection
    accessToken=$(az account get-access-token --resource=https://management.core.windows.net --query "accessToken" -o tsv --subscription $(az account show --subscription $serviceConnectionName --query "id" -o tsv))
    
    # Connect to Azure Function App using SSH
    ssh $instance.scm.azurewebsites.net -t -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa \
        "curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
        curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
        apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 mssql-tools unixodbc-dev && \
        sed -i \"/export PATH=\\\$PATH:\\/opt\\/mssql-tools\\/bin/d\" ~/.bashrc && echo \"export PATH=\\\$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin\" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc"

> 2023-04-23T12:57:01.9869780Z Variable reference is not valid. ':' was
> not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to
> 2023-04-23T12:57:01.9871286Z delimit the name.
> 2023-04-23T12:57:01.9871775Z At
> D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1682254599147_inlinescript.ps1:16
> char:102 2023-04-23T12:57:01.9872397Z + ... sql-tools\\/bin/d\"
> ~/.bashrc && echo \"export PATH=\\\$PATH:/opt/mss ...
> 2023-04-23T12:57:01.9872797Z +                                        
> ~~~~~~ 2023-04-23T12:57:01.9873368Z Variable reference is not valid.
> ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider
> using ${} to
```

tried double qoutes , `echo` ,I cannot fix this error

Comment: You don't and cannot have access to the underlying VM in a function app or app service. You can't install additional software.